# My border style in CSS doesn't cover the whole body

Tags: html, css, border

I have tried to put it in

```
   body{ border-style: double;}
```

also

```
   #form{border-style: double;}
```

but the border only covers a certain portion

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>

      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head runat="server">
       <title>Checkout</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css" />
      </head>
       <body>
      <form id="form" runat="server">
         <div>
            <img src="banner.jpg" />
             <br /><br />
             <span id ="Checkout">Checkout</span><br /><br />
```

the border just goes around the image and checkout after I put 
                   float:left
 in one of the other IDs in the CSS. If I remove the float then the border works fine.

Please don't down the answer, I'm a student and I'm trying to learn step by step. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/pemefu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: you can set the height for your body explicitly to pixels or better vh. For example: body{ border-style: double; margin:0; padding:0; height: 100vh;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that `body` (and html) has no height set, and it will expand to embrace unfloated elements. As soon you `float` the inner element, the body height will *fall*, collapse.

You need to properly clear your floats on the containing parent element (of the floated element)
You can either:

- set `overflow:auto` to the parent `DIV` element
- or use a special class (again on the parent element):

```
.clearFix:before,
.clearFix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearFix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Additionally, if you want to add border directly to `body`, taking in consideration that `html, body` are set to `100%`, in order to make visible the bottom border you might want to add

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

to your `body` element.

**[jsBin demo of `body` with visible bottom border](http://jsbin.com/pemefu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**